# How to run a task on specific days of the week at a certain time in java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I would like my users to be able to choose which days of the week they want to schedule a certain task to run in Java. As I understand, the ScheduledExecutorService is only able to run a single execution, or execute at fixed rates.
I am able to run a task every day at a specific time, but haven't figured out how to do that for specific days. 
**Is there a way to run my task on specific days of the week (e.g. mon, wed, fri)?** 

Also, I know that there are 3rd party libraries out there that would do well for what I'm asking, such as Quartz, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using only Java APIs.

Comment: timer task can do it... scheduling at a given date

Comment: you could implement the "quartz" layer yourself - but why would you?

Comment: @mtraut I guess I'm just curious if there was a relatively simple way to implement this functionality without Quartz.

Comment: i'm not aware of a "pure native", simple solution

Comment: Ok. I think I'll just stick with Quartz then. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can use `ScheduledExecutorService`. Please refer below link for details.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html